# Possible to convert not well formed HTML to XML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having general question that is possible to convert not well formed HTML to XML using XSLT conversion in the Oxygen Editor?

Comment: Saxon 9 or 10 in the PE and EE edition have an extension function `saxon:parse-html` so inside oXygen you can use them as the XSLT  processor, start with a named template and use the function together with `unparsed-text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to parse HTML in standard XSLT, but (as Martin Honnen mentions) Saxon has an extension function `saxon:parse-html()`, which returns a document node just as if you had parsed XML using the `doc()` function.